# Trigger interface ignore next schedule date

Tags: java, spring, triggers

I'm implementing component which implements spring Trigger, but this trigger ignores my return value.

Method getNextIterationDate() is returning current date plus few minutes.

Im trying to run this trigger by:

```java
myObject.nextExecutionTime(new SimpleTriggerContext())
```

```java
class implements Trigger{
...
    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        if(!shouldRerun()){
            lastCall();
            return null;
        }
        rerun();
        return getNextIterationDate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved my issue.

I implemented additional object (name: A) which implements Runnable interface. Then i injected TaskSheduler interface and executed taskScheduler method

```java
schedule(aObject, triggerObject)
```